# Mobile authentification with php/html/jquery

Tags: php, android, jquery, html

Hello I'm trying to do simple authentification application on android, I use dreamweaver as editor. Well here is the code, please can you tell why I'm not redirected to login.php after a success authentification.

index.html

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Guide touristique</title>
<link href="jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loginform").submit(function() {
    $.post('auth.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) { 
      $("#errorm").html(data); // semicolon missing in your code
    }); // round bracket and semicolon missing in your code
  }); // round bracket missing in your code
  return false;
}); 
</script>

</head> 
<body> 

 <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">

        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
            <div style="text-align:center">
            </div>
            <form id="loginform" method='post'>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textinput2" style="text-align:right">
                           Email:
                        </label>
                        <input id="textinput2" name="login" value="" type="text"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textinput3" style="text-align:right">
                            Password:                            </label>
                        <input id="textinput3" name="password" value="" type="password"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>     
                <h3 id="errorm"> <?php if (isset($_GET['msg'])){ 

          echo "Invalid username or password";    
 } 


 ?></h3>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" data-inline="true" data-  icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" value="login"/>
            </form>





</body>
</html>
```

auth.php

```
<?php
 //Sanitize the POST values
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

         $aqry="SELECT * FROM user WHERE utilisateur='".$login."' AND pswd='".$_POST['password']."'";

           $conn=mysql_query($eqry);  

    if( $conn ){
     //Check whether the query was successful or not



                  if(mysql_num_rows($conn) == 1) {
        //Login Successful

       /* $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($conn);
        $_SESSION['MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['NAME'] = $member['utilisateur'];
*/

        header("location: login.php");
        exit();
        }  
                            else { 
             //Login failed 
         header("Location: mobile/mlogin.php?msg=invalid%20name%20or%20password"); 
              exit(); 
             } 
?>
```

login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>login</title>
</head>

<body>
You're logging on
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the login via an ajax request with $.post(), which means that the redirect you are sending is being captured by the ajax request.  If you look in FireBug or something similar, you should see that the result of the ajax call is actually login.php.

I'd recommend having auth.php always return a json response (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) something like {"result":"success", "redirect":"login.php"} or {"result":"error", "message":"abcd"}

In your ajax response handler:

```
if (data.result == "success") {
    window.location = data.redirect;
} else {
    $("#errorm").html(data.message);
}
```